Taskbar search history and recommended cleanup
Recently, my boss gave me a task, asking me to find out where the recent and recommended items in the search function on the taskbar in Windows 11 are stored and how to clean them up.
I searched for information online and saw that someone stored them in Windows.db. But I used sqlite to open Windows.db and found that it was somewhat different from what the data showed. I couldn’t tell which items were the most recent. Does anyone know the answer?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
